# How to read a CSV uploaded via a Spring REST handler using spark?

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Dataframes. I came across the below piece of code provided by the databricks library to read CSV from a specified path in the file system.

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("../Downlos/2017.csv")
```

Is there any API in csv databricks that parses a byte array from a http request instead of reading from a file system?

Usecase here is to read a multipart(CSV) file uploaded using spring REST handler using Spark Dataframes. I'm looking for a dataframe API that can load a file/byte array as input instead of reading from file system.

From the file read, need to select only those columns in each row that match a given condition(eg. any column value that is not equal to string "play" in each parsed 
row) and save only those fields back to the database.

Can anyone suggest if the above mentioned Usecase is feasible in spark using RDD's/Dataframes?..Any suggestions on this would be of much help.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could add some additional detail to this question. do you want to read a file via http and then parallelize? Is your file so large, that you want to read it in parallel? Are these incoming http requests, and you're trying to build an app using Spark streaming? Why are you using http, and not something more suitable? If you just want to download a file, why not do it via wget or try to mount it?

Comment: Usecase here is to read a multipart(CSV) file uploaded using  spring REST handler using Spark Dataframes. I'm looking for a dataframe API that can load a file/byte array as input instead of reading from file system

Comment: Please read [Why is \“Can someone help me?\” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly convert it to `String` you have to `convert` it `tostring` then you can create `RDD`.
check this: [URL contents to a String or file](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-to-download-url-contents-to-string-file)

```
val html = scala.io.Source.fromURL("https://spark.apache.org/").mkString
val list = html.split("\n").filter(_ != "")
val rdds = sc.parallelize(list)
val count = rdds.filter(_.contains("Spark")).count()
```

`Scala`[fromURL](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/io/Source$.html#fromURL(url:java.net.URL)(implicitcodec:scala.io.Codec):scala.io.BufferedSource)`Api`